# Why is my custom sign in controller returning 200?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I'm passing in

```
{"email":"invalidemail@gibberish.com"}
```

as the parameters.

I'm getting a `200` response with a nil body. Why do I not see a `401`?

When I run the first

```
User.where('email = ?', params[:email]).first
```

query in the console, I get nil. I've also tried with passwords, testing invalid passwords. In the console, it fails. But I keep getting a `200` response here:

```
  def sign_in    
    user = User.where('email = ?', params[:email]).first
    if !user
      render :json => user, status => 401
      return
    end

    if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render :json => user
      return
    end

    render :json => user, status => 401
  end
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `:status` and not `status`?

Comment: ..yes.. thank you. I should have gone to sleep.

Comment: delete please. stupid typo.

Comment: It's a typo but the fact that Rails didn't raise an error is interesting. I think it's worth leaving the comment (and answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`head`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses) instead to return just the `401` code without page content :

```
  def sign_in    
    user = User.where('email = ?', params[:email]).first
    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render :json => user
    else 
      head :unauthorized  # 401
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

Although @baldrick is correct that you should use `head` in this case, your question was "Why do I not see a 401?", and to this the answer is: because you have `status` instead of `:status` (a symbol).

This should work:

```
render :json => user, :status => 401
```

As a side note, it was a bit odd to me at first that when you put `status` you didn't get a `NameError` since you're calling a method that (I thought) doesn't exist. But in fact `status` is defined in Rails' `ActionController::Base`, in the [`RackDelegation` module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb), where it delegates to a default response object (`@_response`):

```
delegate :headers, :status=, :location=, :content_type=,
         :status, :location, :content_type, :to => "@_response"
```

So `status` evaluates to `@_response.status`, which (initially at least) is set to 200 (ok).

Thus, `render :json => user, status => 401` is equivalent to `render :json => user, 200 => 401`. The `200 => 401` is simply ignored because it doesn't match any defined options, and you get a 200 response code instead of the expected 401.

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: ARG. Thank you. I was up for way too long yesterday.